# How to add youtube videos in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, youtube

I am new in the coding and development and I want a guideline from you guys in the below said question, kindly help me in this regard! I want to make an app which could use the Firebase database and use the videos in it. Kindly show me the way by which I could add the videos to the Firebase and then play them in my android app.
Thanking You!

Comment: so do you mean to save url to firebase database and later retrieve it and play that video?? or do u want to download the video from YT, and save it in firebase storage?

Answer (score 3):

You can store the URL path to the YouTube video in either Realtime Database or better, Firestore. When reading this data, you can insert the URL into your app or call the appropriate API calls.

**Traditional implementation**

Android has a dedicated YouTube API which requires some setup

- API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

This does require your app to be registered with Google Cloud Project

- GCA:  https://code.google.com/apis/console/

*The above does come with many limitations and I do not recommend it.*

**Web View**

It is suggested to use WebView as it has a better user experience over dedicated integration

```js
WebView youtubeWebView;
String myVideoYoutubeId = "videoID";

outubeWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });

WebSettings webSettings = youtubeWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

youtubeWebView.loadUrl("https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + myVideoYoutubeId);
```

**XML code**

```js
<WebView
        android:id="@+id/youtube_web_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add videos in firebase to play. Simple make a webview Fragment/Activity for YouTube url.